# How to handle TokenMismatchException

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to handle **TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:** exception and then redirect user to login page.

The error occurs when user is logged and and clear browser data (session, history etc) or the user's session expires.

I've already tried the following solution in *Handler.php*:

```
if ($e instanceof TokenMismatchException) {
    return redirect()->route('welcome');
}
```

Full Haler.php code:

```
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler {

    protected $dontReport = [
        AuthorizationException::class,
        HttpException::class,
        ModelNotFoundException::class,
        ValidationException::class,
    ];

    public function report(Exception $e)
    {
        parent::report($e);
    }

    public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {

      if ($e instanceof TokenMismatchException) {
        return redirect()->route('welcome');
      }

      return parent::render($request, $e);

    }
}
```

I've also tried to return the status code and then try to handle it, but when I return status code by `$e->getStatusCode()` it does not return any value. Therefore I don't know how to handle this exception.

Any reasonable suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to handle the `TokenMismatchException` from your `app/Exceptions/Handler`then you need to remove it from the `$dontReport` array in your `Handler` class

```
/**
 * A list of the exception types that should not be reported.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $dontReport = [
    \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException::class,
    \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException::class,
    \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException::class,
    \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException::class,
    // \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException::class, --> delete this line
    \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException::class,
];
```

Although, I would warn you that redirecting the user to the login page on this exception isn't really the right way to handle this.

A `TokenMismatchException` is thrown when the [csrf token](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf) doesn't match. CSRF protection is for both logged in users and guests. So, redirecting to the login page is not really a solution to this problem.

Comment: I don't have TokenMismatchException in `dontReport` array. So how should I solve it?